# varnish 3 varnishlog show missed URL

Tags: varnish

I'm trying to display missed URLs in varnishlog.
The following command returns the whole transaction:

```
varnishlog -m "TxHeader:X-Cache: miss"
```

I would like to display only the requested URL, but the following command show nothig:

```
varnishlog -m "TxHeader:X-Cache: miss" -i RxURL
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

varnish version is 3.0.2-1ubuntu0.1 on Ubuntu server

Comment: Please update your question with sample output of those commands, and what you expect to see instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
varnishlog | grep -i BereqURL
```

BereqURL provides the url links that is not served by varnish cache.

Comment: How do I also see the full URL/hostname that prepends the URI?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
varnishlog -m "TxHeader:X-Cache: miss" -i TxURL
```

`RxURL` is what is **R**eturned from cache; `TxURL` is what is **T**ransmitted to the backend (hence a miss) -- at least that is how I remember these.

Comment: `varnishlog: invalid option -- 'm'` when I try this with `varnish-5.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

Though I'd like to find a way to do this without grep, this works for me...

```
varnishlog  -m "VCL_call:miss"  | grep "RxURL"
```

I found that only RxURL is shown if you use `-m "VCL_call:miss"`.